# reactive forms: inject form-values in service with angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to use two form-values in a service. 
But i didn't get the method/syntax to inject the values in the service, to give them out in other components.
Here is the code for my forms:

**form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-formurl',
  templateUrl: './formurl.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formurl.component.css']
})
export class FormurlComponent  {

  rForm: FormGroup;
  post: any;            // property: weitergeben an Service
  url: string = '';
  name: string = '';


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.rForm = fb.group({
      'name': [''],
      'url': ['']
    });

  }


  addPost(post) {

    this.name = post.name;
    this.url = post.url;

    }

}
```

**form.component.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]='rForm'  (ngSubmit)="addPost(rForm.value)">

    <label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="name">
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="url">
    </label>

    <input type="submit" class="button expanded" value="Submit Form">

</form>
```

And i want to inject the values 'name' and 'url' in this service:
**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AddwmslayerService {


  addlayer = {

    addlayername: ??????????????? ,
    addlayerurl: ??????????????????,

  };

  constructor() { }

}
```

Thank you very much for every suggested potential solution.
I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a set method in the service and then call it after the form has been submitted. But you have to provide the service in your app.module.ts.

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AddwmslayerService {


  addlayer = {

    addlayername: '',
    addlayerurl: '',

  };

  constructor() { }

  setLayer(name: string, url: string) {
    this.addlayer.addlayername = name;
    this.addlayer.addlayerurl = url;
  }

}
```

**form.component.ts**

```
...
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private addLayerService: AddwmslayerService) {

    this.rForm = fb.group({
        'name': [''],
        'url': ['']
    });

}


addPost(post) {

    this.name = post.name;
    this.url = post.url;

    this.addLayerService.setLayer(this.name, this.url);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't understand how to handle the last line in the form.component.ts. I get a error from 'this.AddwmslayerService.setLayer()'. I provided the service in the app.module.

Comment: Have you add the dependency 'private addLayerService: AddwmslayerService' in the constructor of the form.component.ts?

Comment: Thanks a lot, now its working;) Just out of interest: Do you know how to inject both values directly in a component without a service? That would be also a nice solution.

Comment: If the form-component and the component that uses the data have the same parent, then you could use Input() and Output() declarators of the components to transfer the data from one component over the parent to another component. More information here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction